# Linux point LD_LIBRARY_PATH to correct location

Tags: linux, path, caffe, protoc

I am trying to install caffe on a server where I have no root access and I get the following error

> make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.o] Error 1

This error pointed me to https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/4512

protobuf2.3.0 is installed on the server and I installed protobuf3 on my home directory and I added the locations to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but if I do `protoc --version` it still points to 2.3.0. and `which protoc` says `/usr/bin/protoc` I'm not allowed to delete the 2.3 version.

How can I point to my other installation?

Edit:
At the beginning of the error message is `.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h error: #error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.`

Comment: Please add the complete error message. The last line alone doesn't give us much hint on what's wrong with your setup.

Comment: did you append or prepend the path to protobuf3 libs to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. They need to be prepended to the environment variable,

Comment: yes, i prepend it: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/protobuf3/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: It seems you are refusing files from your previous build with protoc 2.x. Try `make clean` to get rid of old files before trying to build.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to add the directory where your new protoc is installed to your PATH variable. Something like `export PATH=/path/to/your/protobuf/installation/bin:$PATH` should do it, depending on the shell you're using.

Comment: Thank you! `protoc --version` prints libprotoc 3.0.0 now, but I still get the same error when trying to build caffe